# VBA increment the "#" in TextBox#.value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

i need help in VBA coding:
i have nearly 250 TextBox in an user form (is a "matrix" of values), and when user finish fill the boxes, I want to write them in the excel sheet.
I could write all 250 lines as

> WorkSheets(mysheet).Cells(x,y).Value = TextBox#.Value

but this would be very long. I wanna know if there is a way to make something like a while, and increment the # of the textbox. 
Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944693/how-to-fill-many-texbox-by-using-loop-function-in-vba

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't find that post, maybe becouse I didn't associated that to my problem. There I found this ridicously easy way: --formname.Controls("statictext" & id)-- thanks again for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use code as follows which will give you each textbox.  Another option is if the boxes are named with a trailing number (i.e. Txt1, Txt2, etc.), then you could use other code (i.e. Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value

```
Dim cCTL As Control
Dim iCTR As Integer
iCTR = 0
For Each cCTL In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(cCTL ) = "TextBox" Then
        iCTR = iCTR + 1
        WorkSheets(mysheet).Cells(iCTR,y).Value = cCTL.Value
    End If
 Next cCTL
```

Option Two (Since all controls are numbered: Just set the For loop to the proper count of controls, and change the 'mysheet' reference to be the column & row you want.

```
Dim i   As Integer
For i = 1 to 250
    WorkSheets(mysheet).Cells(i+2,y).Value = Me.Controls("ctr" & i).value
Next i
```

Comment: if I understand this code, this is usefull, but not in my case becouse I've other textboxes, and the Me.Controls is the way i did it (anyway, i used formname.Controls, becouse i didn't know that "Me" stands for "the place where I'm now".
Thanks a lot for helps!!!

Comment: did  you use a standard naming pattern for the fields in your matrix that will distinguish them from the fields that you do not want? If not, maybe you should have considered that?

Comment: i use c1r1, c1r2, c1r3, c2r1, c2r3 etc etc.. and the me.Controls is awesome. Thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: Since field names are predictable, see updated answer - Option Two.

Comment: Is that I've done. Thanks a lot. I like when someone give some hints, and i've to study. The updated part i very usefull but I think learning is betther without an "already done" code. 
Thanks a lot ofr all time spent for me, I apreciate a lot!